# Nesting widgets in Flutter

Tags: flutter

Is nesting widgets in Flutter, for example, wrapping Column() with SingleChildScrollView() or ListView() good practice? How does it affect the app workload and optimization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core design principle of Flutter is its layered system. You layer widgets on top of each other to compose the desired UI. However, there are multiple limitations, many of each are discussed in the official docs.

You should not wrap a `Column` with a `SingleChildScrollView` directly,

> Doing so, however, usually results in a conflict between the Column,
> which typically tries to grow as big as it can, and the
> SingleChildScrollView, which provides its children with an infinite
> amount of space.

- https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html

The solution is to use a `LayoutBuilder` to obtain the `viewport`'s constraints, and wrapping the `Column` with a `ConstrainedBox` to impose them, as shown in this code snippet: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html#widgets.SingleChildScrollView.1